# Reading the last record of a file

Tags: cobol

I have a COBOL program that requires a transaction number every run of the program. I am planning to get the last transaction number from the file and add 1 to it. The problem is I don't know how to get the last recorded value.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. INVENTORY-SYS.
AUTHOR. LINSEY.
DATE-WRITTEN. 2/22/2015.
DATE-COMPILED. 2/22/2015.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
CONFIGURATION SECTION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
    FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT MASTER-FILE ASSIGN TO "inventory-file.txt"
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD MASTER-FILE.
01 IN-RECORDS.
    02 IN-CODE PIC 9(7).
    02 IN-NAME PIC X(30).
    02 IN-PRICE PIC 9(3).
    02 IN-STOCK PIC 9(4).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-EOF PIC A(1).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
100-READ-FILE.
OPEN I-O MASTER-FILE.
PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF = "Y"
READ MASTER-FILE
 AT END
      MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF
 NOT AT END
    DISPLAY IN-RECORDS
END-READ
END-PERFORM
CLOSE MASTER-FILE.
STOP RUN.
```

This is the sample program. The problem is it retrieves all the records from the file I only the last record from "inventory-file.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are insistent, so:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. INVENTORY-SYS.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
CONFIGURATION SECTION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
    FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT MASTER-FILE ASSIGN TO "inventory-file.txt"
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL
    FILE STATUS IS w-if-in-file-status.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD MASTER-FILE.
01 IN-RECORDS.
    02 IN-CODE PIC 9(7).
    02 IN-NAME PIC X(30).
    02 IN-PRICE PIC 9(3).
    02 IN-STOCK PIC 9(4).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  w-if-in-file-status PIC XX.
    88  master-file-status-good VALUE ZERO "10".
    88  end-of-master-file VALUE "10".
01  w-save-code PIC 9(7).

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    OPEN INPUT MASTER-FILE
    [code to check FILE STATUS field]
    PERFORM UNTIL end-of-master-file
        READ MASTER-FILE
        [code to check FILE STATUS field]
        MOVE IN-CODE to w-save-code
    END-PERFORM
    DISPLAY ">" w-save-code "<"
    CLOSE MASTER-FILE
    [code to check FILE STATUS field]
    GOBACK
    .
```

I don't know why your IN-CODE field is numeric. Are you going to do calculations with it?

---

You keep a Control File. That has a date (to match to the Business Date file) a logical file-name, an environment and the last transaction number.

You maintain that file, checking everything as you do so.

Comment: I already did that.  sir my question is how can I get the last record from the file. using a ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

Comment: When you have finished with your transaction numbers for the day, you update the Control File. You don't read a file specifically to do that, you do it at the same time you are processing functionality. How, otherwise, would you ensure you are reading the correct file, in the correct environment, at the correct time, etc?

Comment: no sir this transaction is not a day to day basis. each time the program runs the transaction number must be updated. example sir 00001 is the first number of transaction once the program run it will be save on another file. when the user runs the program again the transaction number must be 00002.  I can only do this if i can get the last transaction and add 1 to it when I run the program in the second time

Comment: @T_T OK, it just means your "day" is short. Same process. Use a Control File. Can you update your question with the details from the comments (use the edit link, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28828462/edit, under the question) and show some examples to be as clear as possible. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Windows 7 and I am Using OpenCobol IDE for compiling cobol programs

Comment: SIR THANK YOU VERY MUCH :D :D :D, yes sir I am going to do a calculation to calculate the new transaction number :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of OpenCobol supports it, but you might try using OPEN/REVERSED.  It is an old school way of reading a tape backwards, or these days, a virtual tape.  I've no idea if it is implemented, but it is an easy way to read a sequential file backwards.